# context.lookup in not working in weblogic

Tags: ejb-3.0

i am new in ejb3 application
my project is:
ServletController.java

```
package controller;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import com.HelloUser;

public class ServletController extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void service(HttpServletRequest arg0, HttpServletResponse arg1) throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            InitialContext Context = new InitialContext();
            Context context = new InitialContext();
            HelloUser helloUser = (HelloUser) context.lookup("ejb3/" + HelloUser.class.getSimpleName() + "/local");
            System.out.println(".................................");
            helloUser.sayHello("reza");
            arg1.sendRedirect("reza");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

HelloUser.java:

```
package com;

import javax.ejb.Local;

@Local
public interface HelloUser {
    public void sayHello(String name);
}
```

HelloUserBean.java

```
package com;

import javax.ejb.Stateless;

@Stateless
public class HelloUserBean implements HelloUser {
    public HelloUserBean() {
    }

    public void sayHello(String name) {
        System.out.println("Hello " + name + " welcome to EJB 3!");
    }

}
```

web.xml

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <display-name>Baharan-Framework</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>Index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>controller.ServletController</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
</web-app>
```

the following error is raised when ServletController is called by webbrowser(URL is:http://localhost:7001/weblogic/rest/jkfg):

```
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: While trying to lookup 'ejb3.HelloUser/local' didn't find subcontext 'ejb3'. Resolved ''; remaining name 'ejb3/HelloUser/local'
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.BasicNamingNode.newNameNotFoundException(BasicNamingNode.java:1139)
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.BasicNamingNode.lookupHere(BasicNamingNode.java:247)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Weblogic print all jndi names assigned to every Enterprise bean, and you can get it directly. The second, remove context.lookup("ejb3/" + HelloUser.class.getSimpleName() + "/local"); then in simple cases this function can helps you:

```
public static <T>T lookupBean(Class<T> beanClass) {
final String jndiName = "java:module/" + beanClass.getSimpleName();
        logger.info("lookup : {}", jndiName);

        try {
            T bean = InitialContext.doLookup(jndiName);
            logger.info("detected : {}", bean);
            return bean;
        }

        catch(NamingException e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
            return null;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide me deployments log?? and rather then trying using initialcontext lookup with @EJB annotation.